# openmp: different answer using ifort than gfortran

Tags: openmp

I have recently encountered a compiler specific openmp issue. I have written a code that works correctly using openmp and gfortran. I have recently used ifort and openmp to compile the same code, and now the openmp section segfaults. I have cut most of the fat away, and wrote this snippet of code which reproduces my error

```
!$omp parallel do schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:energy) default(private) shared(r,tr)

     do i=0,listvar%ncellT-1

           c1s = tr(i)%start
           c1e = tr(i)%end

           do j = c1s,c1e

              x1 = r(j)%x; y1 = r(j)%y; z1 = r(j)%z
              energy = energy + x1
           enddo
        enddo

        !$omp end parallel do
```

All this loop does is access pointers to elements in r from the array tr, and then loop between those elements. However, ifort is for some reason assigning nonsense values to c1s and c1e causing the code to segfault when I loop over r. Again, the code works with gfortran. Does anyone have any idea why this may be?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. For some reason, gfortran was kind enough to initialize the variable listvar for all threads! IFORT however, requires the use of firstprivate. I am really surprised gfortran never threw an error here. I have ran the code using gfortran over a wide range of conditions, and it worked every time.

Comment: This called undefined behavior. You shouldn't be surprised at all.